# Google AdMob API to create Ad Units and Mediation Groups

Tags: google-api, admob, google-api-python-client

Is there a way to create AdUnits and MediationGroups using Google AdMobAPI? Is there any scope that allows you to do so?

I've searched all across the net and couldn't find anything that suggests that, even due that in Google's documentation it shows like it is possible. [Check it here](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/reference/rest/v1beta/accounts.mediationGroups/create).